# C++ threading classes not working and giving functional and thread file errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I am very frustrated that this is not working. I read most of the stackoverflow comments and examples and none of it shown to work. I just started doing c++.

I want the code to print "Hello World".

Here's a sample of my code (I can give my full code but I will be unnecessary since there is a lot of code in it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Greeting {
    public:
        void hi() {
           cout << "Hello World!\n";
        }
};

int main() {

Greeting g;

thread t(g.hi);
t.join();

return 0;
}
```

Error:

> ```
> ||=== Build: Debug in Cookie Island (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional
> ||In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_check_arity<void (Greeting::*)()>':|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional
> |1538|required from 'struct std::_Bind_simple_helper<void (Greeting::*)()>'|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional
> |1552|  required by substitution of 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> 
> typename std::_Bind_simple_helper<_Func, _BoundArgs>::__type 
> std::__bind_simple(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) 
> [with _Callable = void (Greeting::*)(); _Args = {}]'|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\thread
> |142|required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) 
> [with _Callable = void (Greeting::*)(); _Args = {}]'|
> C:\Users\Andrew Shen\Desktop\Cookie Island\main.cpp|51|required from here|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional
> |1426|error: static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional
> ||In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Greeting::*)()>()>':|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\thread
> |142|required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) 
> [with _Callable = void (Greeting::*)(); _Args = {}]'|
> C:\Users\Andrew Shen\Desktop\Cookie Island\main.cpp|51|required from here|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional
> |1505|error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Greeting::*)()>()>'|
> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional
> |1526|error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Greeting::*)()>()>'|
> ||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 7 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
> ```

Update:
This is more like my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Greeting {
    public:
        void hi(string txt) {
           cout << "Hello World!"+txt << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
string t = " More...";

Greeting g;

thread t(g.hi, &g, t);
t.join();

return 0;
}
```

> Blockquote
>   ||=== Build: Debug in Cookie Island (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional||In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple)>(Greeting*, std::__cxx11::basic_string*)>':|
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\thread|142|required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Greeting::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string); _Args = {Greeting*, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >*}]'|
>   C:\Users\Andrew Shen\Desktop\Cookie Island\main.cpp|52|required from here|
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional|1505|error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of)>(Greeting*, std::__cxx11::basic_string*)>'|
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional|1526|error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of)>(Greeting*, std::__cxx11::basic_string*)>'|
>   ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

Comment: One quick solution: Don't use a member function, use a lambda that calls your member function.

Comment: @druckermanly How are you suppose to do lambda. More specifically in this type of situation.

Comment: Really _anything_ would be easier here than the non-static member function you have. These need extra work because they require a hidden extra argument (the `this` pointer to the instance you're invoking the function on). A simple free function will be fine, since you have no instance data in `Greeting` anyway.

Comment: Notably you can't just pass the implicit `this` pointer as an explicit argument, as you tried. A lambda like `[&](std::string s) { g.hi(s); }` (replacing the first two arguments to the thread constructor) is the simplest way to get your current scheme working.

Comment: I said *part* of my code above. Meaning my full code actually has an instances.

Comment: Sorry if this confused you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member functions are not part of objects but class. You need full qualified function name. You need to do following:

```
thread t(&Greeting::hi, &g, str);
```

Also, you accidentally used 't' as name of staring variable and for the thread, which i modified to str for string.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone of the following works,

```
string str = " More...";

thread t(Greeting::hi, g, str);
```

or,

```
thread t(&Greeting::hi, g, str);
```

or,

```
thread t(Greeting::hi, &g, str);
```

or,

```
thread t(&Greeting::hi, &g, str);
```

Can you explain the difference among all those situations, Please. @Abhinav